# Visual artifacts and glitches in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

I've started receiving visual glitches on my Windows 10 work pc. As far as I know, nothing has really changed, no new software, no new graphics driver updates. In fact, what might be going on is that I can't really find the Intel graphics settings anymore, though I'm unsure if they we're ever there as I don't recall I've never accessed them on that pc.

Examples of glitch in Settings app:

[image]

It only seems to happen in opened windows and lock screen, not on the desktop. I'm mostly seeing it in chrome and the Win10 settings windows. Also, it is happening when I access the computer through remote desktop. Sadly I don't have access to the computer any other way since of the pandemic.

Now, it might be that it isn't visible in the screenshots as they don't seem to be having the artifacts when looking at the miniatures in explorer. I might have to shoot some cellphone pictures to get the examples.

Screenshot of the remote desktop from my personal pc

[image: Screenshot of the remote desktop from my personal pc]

Thanks for reading, please tell me if you need any further info.

Comment: Graphics glitches that appear onscreen but not in screenshots usually turn out to be hardware issues - the image is being sent correctly by the computer, but failing by the time it reaches the screen

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, that's my thought as well though I'm unsure on how to proceed with testing exactly what's wrong

Comment: The weird thing is the glitch over RDC, which doesn't add up somehow. I'm at a loss to explain that.